# Why does this servlet return a content-length different from the number of bytes of the content?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a Java servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String text = "1234567890";
    System.out.println("bytes = "+text.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(text);
}
```

The returned text takes 10 bytes. Why if I don't set the Content-Length header myself I get a Content-Length of 12 with the response?

Comment: `println` will print a newline as well. If this is a windows machine, maybe you're getting a CR+LF in the end? Try `print` instead and see what happens.

Comment: yes... that was the problem. Thank you very much... I feel so silly for not thinking about it ;)